# Why Geoprocessing service show only one result?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service

I've searched a lot before posting this question.

I've created with model builder on ArcGIS 10.2.2 a model for clipping a point shapefile.

It works correctly on desktop, but when I publish it as a geoprocessing service and ask it to run, the result is only one point instead of the total number of features that should be clipped.

Any help or advice?

Comment: I'm using both arcgis server and desktop 10.2.2